# Extreme values with ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

I am trying to plot a histogram using `ggplot()` however I am unable to deal with extreme values. I would like them to be comined within one bin (called "500 and more" for example).

I have tried the `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,500, by = 50))` function but it just removes labels from the x-axis (attached below) Any ideas of how to deal with this?[image]

Comment: Could you please post the data so that we can work with it?

Comment: Your best might be to bin the data first, and then make a barplot instead of a histogram.

Comment: The result won't be a histogram anymore.

Comment: @Roland Why not? Isn't a histogram a bar plot with a binned x axis and frequency on the y?

Comment: @Zimano An unlimited bin like "500 and more" is not allowed in a histogram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to compute counts before the plotting. Using function `cut()` you can set breaks as you need and plot those data using `geom_bar()`. Setting width=1 inside the `geom_bar()` will remove space between bars.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2movies)
data("movies")
df<-movies %>% mutate(length.class=cut(length,breaks=c(seq(0,500,50),10000))) %>%
      group_by(length.class) %>% summarise(count=n())

ggplot(df,aes(length.class,count))+geom_bar(stat="identity",width=1)
```

[image]

Comment: That works and is extremely clearly presented at the same time! Thank you very much, I appreciate your help!